# Glide - How load image before dialog show?

Tags: android, android-glide

I'm working with Glide for server loading images. I need to load image before some dialog shows.

What is the best approach?

EDIT: This is an example from my code:

```
    On my dialog class

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        setContentView(R.layout.dialog_alert);
        ButterKnife.bind(this);

        int size = mActivity.getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.product_icon);
        String productThumbnailUrl = api.getThumbnailUrl(mProduct.getImage(), size, size);

        Glide.with(mActivity)
        .load(productThumbnailUrl)
        .placeholder(R.drawable.icon_default)
        .into(mImage);
    }

    On my activity:

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        [...]

        AlertProduct dialog = new AlertProduct(this, product);
        dialog.show();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

[Loading into targets](https://github.com/bumptech/glide/wiki/Custom-targets) should do what you want.

> If you simply want to load a Bitmap so that you can interact with it
>   in some special way other than displaying it directly to the user,
>   maybe to show in a notification, or upload as a profile photo, Glide
>   has you covered.
>
> SimpleTarget provides reasonable default implementations for the much
>   larger Target interface and let's you focus on handling the result of
>   your load.

Comment: Yes, but is not that simple. Im trying to load image using glide in onCreate of my dialog so I don't know how can override method show so that dialog is't displayed until the image is loaded.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? It would be easier to help you if you had some code posted.

Comment: what is this , show the code documentation is meaningless without it